# How can I display the number of post associated to a category in Twig/Timber Wordpress?

Tags: categories, templates

I am using the following code to access my categories.

```
$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'exclude'    => 18,
);
$context['categories'] = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
$total_in_term = $context['categories']->count;
$context['TotalInTerm'] = $total_in_term;
```

And trying to display the category name following by number of posts that each term has in brackets after it:

```
{% for cat in categories %}
      <a href="{{ site.link }}/{{ cat.slug }}">{{ cat.name }} ({{ TotalInTerm }})</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

I am trying to get it to output like this:
**Category Name** **(   { number of posts in category }   )**

So far I have it outputting the category name and link only but not the number of posts it holds. Can someone help?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to wrap `TotalInTerm` in `{{ ... }}` to get the variable? ie, `({{TotalInTerm}})`? (nm, I see you've updated the question to reflect this)

Comment: What *does* display inside the `()` at the end? What does `var_dump( $context['TotalInTerm'] );` display?

Comment: @Pat J Nothing is displaying inside `()` at the end at it's not working. `var_dump` displays NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) returns an object with a `count` property, but it doesn't.

From the docs:

> ### Return
>
> *(WP_Term[]|int[]|string[]|string|WP_Error)* Array of terms, a count thereof as a numeric string, or WP_Error if any of the taxonomies do not exist. See the function description for more information.

Also, the way you're calling `get_terms()` is deprecated. There should be only one argument, an array that includes the taxonomy name.

So here's how I'd update the code:

```
$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false;

$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'exclude'    => 18,
);
$context['categories'] = get_terms( $cat_args );
// Gets the count in a separate call.
$cat_args['fields'] = 'count';
$total_in_term = get_terms( $cat_args );
$context['TotalInTerm'] = $total_in_term;
```

### References

- [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)
- [`fields` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/get_terms/)